# \pgfresetboundingbox is undefined control sequence?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm sure this question has a simple answer that I'm missing: I'm trying to use pgfplots to put two graphs right next to each other with no space in between.  I thought I could do this by using the \pgfresetboundingbox command found in the manual.  However, LaTeX gives me an undefined control sequence error on this command.  What am I doing wrong?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ylabel={$\hat{\delta}$},
xlabel={$x$}
]
\addplot table[x index=0, y index=2, header=false]{probset1.txt};
\end{axis}
\pgfresetboundingbox
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{0cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={$x$},
ytick=\empty
]
\addplot table[x index=0, y index=3, header=false]{probset1.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please add a [complete, compilable but *minimal* example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Would be nice with a compilable example. However, with some dummy data your example compiles fine for me, perhaps you need to update PGF/PGFPLOTS. It doesn't give the output you wanted though, but what about removing the `\pgfresetboundingbox` and adding some negative `hspace`? Not ideal, but it may work.

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches:

1. Include the axes in the same `tikzpicture` and place them using the axis nodes `south east` and `south west`, which lie on the corners of the axes.
2. Reset the bounding box as you suggested (probably after updating your `pgf`), then set the axis as the new bounding box.

Here's example code for both methods:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[anchor=south east,
width=5cm,
ylabel={$\hat{\delta}$},
xlabel={$x$}
]
\addplot coordinates {(1,1) (2,1.5)};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[anchor=south west,
width=5cm,
xlabel={$x$},
ytick=\empty
]
\addplot coordinates {(1,1.4) (2,1.1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=5cm,
ylabel={$\hat{\delta}$},
xlabel={$x$}
]
\addplot coordinates {(1,1) (2,1.5)};
\end{axis}\pgfresetboundingbox
\useasboundingbox
(current axis.below south west)
rectangle (current axis.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=5cm,
xlabel={$x$},
ytick=\empty
]
\addplot coordinates {(1,1.4) (2,1.1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]